# What are these words meaning in Soul Calibur terminology?

Tags: soul-calibur-4

I've made a custom character in Soul Calibur IV and I'm able to choose some skills but I don't understand them. There are some **keywords** which are not really clear like:

- impact
- guard breaker
- counter

I tried the SC wiki but there is no thorough explanation how these work. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Guard Impact

A Guard Impact (or just "Impact" for short) is a counter where you press forward/back plus guard at the same time. If you time it right, you will push your opponents attack away and stagger him a bit, giving you time to follow up with free damage (unless he Guard Impacts you back). You can Guard Impact with forward/back, which blocks high and mid attacks, or with downforward/downback, which blocks low attacks.

## Guard Breaker

Any attack you do that has an extra blue fiery animation is a Guard Breaker. If your opponent blocks it, it will break his guard and stagger him for a few seconds. It is usually difficult to actually follow this up with damage because of the recovery frames on your own attack.

## Counter

Any attack you make that hits your opponent during one of his animations is a counter. You can tell if a hit is a counter hit because the little explosion animation will be red instead of the normal yellow for generic hits. There are different kinds of counter hits (a run counter if you hit your opponent while running vs. an attack counter if you hit him while he's in the middle of attacking). The type of counter you get (and whether you get a counter at all) will affect your opponent's recovery speed from the hits. You can get longer, more damaging combos off counter hits than normal hits.